# LINQ gives different results against XML and Db

Tags: c#, linq

I have an xml containing account details of employees. I am trying to calculate the total Sum using LINQ. I have the following query:

```
var totalSum = (from account in accounts
               where account.Status == "active"
               select account.Balance).Sum();
```

I also went ahead and parsed the data into a database table. When I run it against my xml I have a different result and when I run it against my db I have a different one. I checked the parser and all the entries are parsed correctly.

I also ran a SQL query to calculate the Sum and that matches with the LINQ query againt the db. Really cannot figure out what the problem is since my parser is correct.

Comment: Try `where account.Status.Trim().ToLower() == "active"`

Comment: That doesn't look like valid Linq-to-Xml.  In the xml case what is the exact type of `accounts`.  What is it in the Linq-to-SQL case?

Comment: How much different is the result? Rounding-error level different, or lots of uncounted data different?

Comment: Yes it works now. But why? The data is the same in xml and db.

Comment: I'm going to distract you from the issue, but you already have the right answer. With normalization: a table called `Status` with fields `Description` {Active, Closed, etc} and `ID`, which would join into table `Account` on field `StatusID`, would most likely have prevented this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably did not have all of your record status "active" in lower case or with no trailing spaces.

When `accounts` is a `DbSet` object it is set up with default case-insensitive config. Hence the where expression would still match "Active" or "ACTIVE". However, if `accounts` is in memory it would not match and hence you are getting different results.

This should work

```
var totalSum = (from account in accounts
        where account.Status.Trim().ToLower() == "active"
        select account.Balance).Sum();
```